# Self-hosted Parse Platform RESTful API access

Tags: node.js, parse-server

I'm using Parse for some quick MVP app development to prove some concepts. Everything is working fine and I'm simply trying to extend the abilities of our app by setting up some 3rd party integrations etc.

I would like to access my Cloud Code functions via the RESTful api, as documented [here](http://parseplatform.github.io/docs/rest/guide/#cloud-code)

I've changed the server address, but have no luck connecting and pulling the data.

I am using Node.js to connect to the REST api, which is being hosted on Heroku.

```
var options = {
        host: 'https://###############.herokuapp.com',
        port: 443,
        path: '/parse/functions/'+req.param('text'),
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'X-Parse-Application-Id': '##############',
            'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': '###########'
        }
    };
    https.get(options, function(resp){
      resp.on('data', function(chunk){
        //do something with chunk
        res.send(chunk)
      });
    }).on("error", function(e){
      console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
      res.send(e)
    });
```

So far no luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you receiving any response from the server?  Could you also share the code where you instantiate the Parse Server in index.js?

Comment: Not enough information to have a right answer. Please paste here your Parse Server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell what exactly is wrong without seeing the Parse Server configuration, the Cloud Code function, and more importantly the server's response, but here's what worked for me:

> curl -X POST   -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: XYZUASDASDA"   -H
>   "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: XYZUASDASDA"   -H "Content-Type:
>   application/json"   -d '{}'
>   http://localhost:3000/parse/functions/averageStars

Result: {"result":"Hello"}

Here's my test Cloud Code function:

> Parse.Cloud.define('averageStars', function(request, response) {
>       response.success('Hello'); });

As a quick test, I suggest:

1. Try using CURL
2. Try the test function above